# Not able to hide a bootstrap button

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to hide a bootstrap button. I should be able to see them only when I click on a checkbox. However I'm not able to achieve. Can anyone please help?

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" value="{{todo.task_name}}">
<span class="done-{{todo.done}}"> {{todo.task_name}}</span>         
<a id="done-modal-button" ng-click='onCompleteTask(todo)' ng-model="todo.done" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Done</a>
```

JS

```
$('#done-modal-button').hide();
```

Comment: #done-button or #done-modal-button?

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal I'm sorry. #done-modal-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need Jquery to do this!
You only have to change this line:

```
<a id="done-modal-button" ng-click='onCompleteTask(todo)' ng-model="todo.done" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Done</a>
```

To this:

```
<a id="done-modal-button" ng-click='onCompleteTask(todo)' ng-show="todo.done" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Done</a>
```

You want to show the link only when the "todo.done" is true

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9139/

I suggest you read this post:

["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. It was idiotic on my part to not think on this line. Thanks a lot @Fabrico.

Comment: Great answer, I'm not familiar with Angular and wanted to give him a working answer till he found out a proper way :D +1 from me :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS `display:none` to hide it :

```
<a id="done-modal-button" ng-click='onCompleteTask(todo)' ng-model="todo.done" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" style="display:none;">Done</a>
```

**Update based on your comment**

To toggle visibility depending on weather a checkbox is checked or not you need to see if it's checked first, and if it is, show the button, else hide it back.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#checkboxid').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $('#done-modal-button').show();
        } else {
            $('#done-modal-button').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**[Working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/hqsdpn9f/)**

**Update 2**

I guess you have no other jquery library in your script, to use the method above you could use the method in the jsfiddle I gave you in the comment OR you could load jquery-1.9.1 and it will work, see this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/hqsdpn9f/1/) with AngularJS and jQuery-1.9.1

To load the library just add this inside your head tags:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: that worked. Thanks a lot. Any idea on how I can make it display is a checkbox is checked.

Comment: @krish_cloudnow you want to make it visible when a ckechbox is checked and hidden when not ?

Comment: @krish_cloudnow I updated my answer and also added a working jsfiddle with how the checkbox works. If this answers your question, feel free to mark it :)

Comment: It is working fine in ur JSfiddle. I tried making changes and no issues. However not working in my code. I'm using AngularJS & Bootstrap. Is there any other issue?

Comment: @krish_cloudnow Things change if you are using AngularJS, check this jsfiddle to see how a checkbox action works in angluar : http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/JBwmA/

Comment: @krish_cloudnow I've made another update to the answer using Angular..It has to work now :)